# PRU UART on the BeagleBone Black

Tags: linux, uart, beagleboneblack

I am trying to get the PRU UART of the BeagleBone Black to send/receive 9-bits data.
I used the stick parity to emulate 8M1 and 8S1 modes but when testing the parity bit is always a 0. it's like always 8S1 mode.
I even tried to emulate the 8M1 mode to 8N2 mode but the test shows only 1 stop bit is sent.
Any solution ?

Comment: How did you configure it? Can you post the register values of the UART?

Comment: '''   
     CT_UART.DLL = 0xE2;
     CT_UART.DLH = 0x4;
     CT_UART.MDR_bit.OSM_SEL = 0x0;
     
     CT_UART.IER = 0x7;
     
     CT_UART.FCR_bit.FIFOEN = 0x1;
     CT_UART.FCR_bit.RXCLR = 0x1;
     CT_UART.FCR_bit.TXCLR = 0x1;
     CT_UART.FCR_bit.RXFIFTL= 0x0;
     
     CT_UART.LCR_bit.WLS = 0x3;
     CT_UART.LCR_bit.STB = 0;
     
     /* for mark parity PEN = 1, EPS = 0 and SP = 1*/
     CT_UART.LCR_bit.PEN = 1;
     CT_UART.LCR_bit.EPS = 0;
     CT_UART.LCR_bit.SP = 1;
'''
     and  the power management register ( can't post it not enough characters)